# JFET stabilised wien bridge component ratios

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, jfet, wien-bridge

I find myself in need of a sine wave oscillator and have decided on the wien bridge. I have followed all the tutorials but have a few questions that do not seem to be answered elsewhere.
[image]

Firstly, I understand the ratio between Rf and R3 determines the negative feedback loop gain set to 3, or just above, at a ratio of 2:1. But there are lots of combinations of resistances which would give that ratio, so what effect would say using a 1 OHM : 2 OHM resistance be compared to 10 OHM : 20 OHM? And the same question about the capacitor resistor combinations in the lead lag circuit.

Second, how do the values of Rf and R3 get selected when there is a JFET paired with R2? I figured that to get a gain of 3 after the gate voltage comes up then I would add the Rds(on) of the JFET to R3 and count them as one, so then when the JFET is off, there would be no resistance through it and the gain would be higher than 3, allowing oscillations to start. Is this correct? Any particular ratio between the JFET Rds(on) and R3, does one dominate, equal or does not matter?

Third, the negative peak detector which drives the gate of the JFET charges a capacitor, which has a resistor in parallel. What is that resistor R4 doing and how is its value determined? How is the capacitors value determined?

Lastly, what determines the output voltage? Say, I need a 0.1 v output to feed a BJT amp, what values would I need to change and how would I calculate them? I figured the output would be determined by the maximum peak to peak printed on the datasheet, but how would I bring this down?

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the control loop Diode-C3-R4:

This is not a peak detector because the parallele resistor R4 continuously discharges the capacitor which - in turn  - is charged by the output amplitude (if it can open the diode at a certain level). This is necessary in order to allow amplitude control in BOTH directions. The opamp gain swings around the nominal value of "3".

Hence, the output amplitude is NOT CONSTANT - it will exhibit a small amplitude modulation which is determined by the time constant C3-R4. This time constant should be at least ten times larger than the oscillation period. From this requirement you can select both values (C3 and R4).

Regarding the ouput amplitude: An exact computation is not possible (due to the nonlinear Diode characteristics). However, a good estimat is possible if you know the nominal value (during steady-state oscillations) of the FET resistance and the corresponding gate voltage. This give you the mean voltage across C3 and - together with app. 0.5 across the diode - a reasonable guess for the corresponding output amplitude.

**EDIT** (error correction):
There is a logical error on your side.

You wrote: *.....when the JFET is off, there would be no resistance through it and the gain would be higher than 3, allowing oscillations to start.*....

No, when the JFET is off the RDS resistance is very large and the opamp works as a unity gain amplifier (full feedback).

The correct description is as follows: At t=0 the ouput voltage (and the gate voltage) is zero and the FET is open - the RDS resistance is low (max current ID) and the gain larger than "3". Now - for rising amplitudes the gate voltage becomes more and more negative and the RDS resistance goes higher and provides more negative feedback (the gain is decreased until it reaches "3").

Comment: would the time constant be 5RC or just RC?

Comment: "This is not a peak detector" is incorrect.  the +DC biased negative swing is detected as a negative peak detects with diode to attenuate negative feedback and boost gain so it starts up FASTER, diode R= << 100 Ohms say, and R4 is probably 10k to 100k to  so fast start RC the slow decay on peak detector to reduce distortion settling on unity gain.

Comment: Although I spent little time making perfect grammar organizing each question with an answer,  at least I answered every question and had no major technical error. but had minor confusing sentence ( agreed :}

Comment: -1 THis is not a peak detector. (Wrong)

Comment: Technically this diode RC acts as a "Quasi-peak detector" where the ideal signal BW ought to be a small % of oscillator frequency for low phase noise and low THD. consequently, this design has too high a feedback gain and BW and is very distorted. Unlike my optimized design. you are thinking of a DMM Vpk and hold detector, which it is not. It is just a quasi peak detector that should hold a bit longer than it does. So there is no effective "quasi" filter and it becomes thus becomes **a negative  peak detector* like in a spectrum analyzer with no video filter uses a peak detector + or -

Comment: To summarize, you define a "peak detector" to only have a DC value, but I define that as a peak and hold detector. Whereas in my lifespan as an Instrument designer, peak detection can have any rise or fall time and simply rectifies the signal. The rise fall time is an additional spec. Whereas you assumed it must be DC or least an average of >=10 peaks.  In any case you ought to examine my results and suggest more improvements to his design as I did.  OK?

Answer (score 1):

Rf is a load on the opamp output. Its value cannot be less than 2k ohms for most opamps so maybe use 20k ohms. Then the resistance of the Jfet plus R3 must be 10k ohms for a gain of 3. Let R3 be maybe 4.7K then the Jfet can be 5.3k.

R4 discharges the capacitor and allows the Jfet to turn on when the output signal level is low. The capacitor value is selected to be a good filter at the lowest frequency you want low distortion.

Allow the output level to be high enough for the circuit to work well, then attenuate it with two series resistors to ground at the output.

Comment: I rather think, the task of the capacitor C3 is not to "filter" anything but to provide a - more or less - fixed DC voltage at the gate of the FET. As I have explained in my detailed answer, the time constant C3R4 causes a small amplitude modualtion of the output signal (which is quite normal because steady-state oscillations exactly at unity loop gain can never be achieved).

Comment: thought most jfet Rds(on) values were around 150 - 400 ohms? 4.7k seems high

Answer (score 1):

### Update July  28

The output level is determined by the Vgs threshold required to make the loop gain exactly unity for a pure sine.  Since there is a Thevenin R5/(R5+R7) ratio with a diode offset which is nulled by another voltage reference (0.75V) in my answer so become a better negative peak detector with an initial condition to get an instant startup of an infinite Q ( or really highQ at steady state ( See filter response in linked answer)) oscillator, and also the FET Vt determines the output amplitude so this 0.75V precharges the cap voltage to Vgs to start with a sine wave.

THus to reduce Vout sine, use a lower Vt and higher ratio of R7/R4. Conversely for a maximal Vout, use a higher Vt and and lower R7/R4 =1 as in my case.

I could have simplified the design to incorporate this bias, but chose not to.

---

**"This is not a peak detector" is incorrect.**  the +DC biased negative swing is detected as a negative peak detects with diode to attenuate negative feedback and boost gain so it starts up FASTER, diode R= << 100 Ohms say, and R4 is probably 10k to 100k to  so fast start RC the slow decay on peak detector to reduce distortion settling on unity gain.  ( JFET has Id=Idss with Vgs=0V which then conducts but also introduces DC offset so output saturates, (not so great) :(

- **peak detectors have some slow decay rate controlled here by R4C3gm** where gm=ΔId/ΔVgs ~ 20m to 50m for some
- the closed loop positive feedback must be slowly regulated to “1.000” depending compression rate of change of FET attenuator vs frequency to satisfy oscillation criteria
- you will see the DIODE attacks fast to bias the JFET ON to reduce the
- for an interactive simulation with a tuning pot [read my better answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426130/why-the-wien-oscillator-output-is-a-sine/426135#426135)
- always start with THD specs or amount of asymmetry of the sinewave,  with output Vpp levels defined and startup time inverse with Q that defines this high Q resonator.
- there are better designs but depends on all your specs for linearity, amplitude, phase noise and startup time, frequency, and controllability, ranges and tolerances, and tuning methods.

did you [search here for WIEN BRIDGE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=wien%20user%3Ame) or Wein (x)

### Design Requirement:

Rf:R2 = 2:1 in the steady state but when 1:1 will startup faster as an oscillator.  Thus negative peak detector decay rate dV/dt on output on R4 times gain gm must be defined for low gain at frequency of oscillation so result is a symmetrical sine with low distortion

> > Rf, R4 absolute values that are too low **like 1,10,100 Ohms are bad** for Op Amps to drive this ( too high a current) and Jfet resistance cannot get this low and 1M is almost too high so what happens if you choose values in between and
>
> **how does gm change with Vgs**?  i.e. where is it maximum?
> Answer: Idss mA is defined by Vgs=0V which produces maximum gm but is reduced only slowly as Vgs rises, then sharply reduces.  Sensitivity only needs to <<1% gain control and this is far too great without attenuators.

This allows a wide tolerance but almost full swing sine output limited also by the "headroom" needed for Op Amp (Vout max+ Vout min) for BJT types vs CMOS Op AMps that are Rail to Rail.

- startup time vs THD harmonic distortion  ( inferior design to Commercial sig generator but cheap and dirty)

Lastly won't need 0.1V to a BJT amp as this  is alarge voltage swing oscillator.  But you need more current drive, then include two transistors as "emitter followers" PNP+NPN to OpAmpout before feedback. (common easy search will show how)

After careful tuning for low distortion and instant startup , amplitude gain control sensitivity reduction and with resistors with Vbias  0.75V+/-20% to put JFET into proper pre-condition for rapid locking to peak detector ,**this is what an excellent sine Oscillator should look like.**
[image]

My optimization were done before but shown now.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95771/discussion-on-answer-by-sunnyskyguy-ee75-jfet-stabilised-wien-bridge-component-r).

Comment: @clabacchio have you ever seen a better performing Sine WIEN Osc.

Comment: A peak detector detects - and holds - the peak value of a periodic signal. However, in our case and under stwady-state conditions, the diode-C-R combination causes the voltage across the capacitior to swing (just a little bit and slowly) around a voltage which is well below the peak value at the opamps output. This is a desired feature and is caused by the continiuous charging/discharging of the capacitor. Each simulation shows this effect.

Comment: A peak detector simply rectifies voltage with a storage capacitance and series and parallel R's affect the rise and decay time.  .  In this case it is a negative peak detector with a Thevenin voltage and resistance due to R5//R7 * 300pF rise time and R7*300pF decay time.  In my design this is 10M/10M * 1nF rise time and 10M * 1nF decay time thus giving much lower BW in the rate of change of FET transconductance as this gain does not require such a large swing at the stable operating point.  It is still a negative peak detector for AGC and my design is far superior due to this @LvW ok?

Comment: @clabacchio  do you understand or agree?  LvW you are thinking of a peak and hold detector that holds for a much larger ratio of decay/rise time to store an accurate peak longer than it decays. So there is a linear aspect to all peak detectors due to these two time constants.  YOur thinking is that is only for large ratios. Tf>>Tr yet Tr is never 0 and Tf is never infinite. They are analog and it is still a peak detector. although lossy due to Thevenin ratios. R5/(R5+R7)

Comment: Thus you can design the output amplitude knowing the Vt for the FET and this ratio relative to the circuit Z or the required Vgs to attenuate the input signal for a required output voltage less than saturation. Would you like me to show the equations? or can you figure that out for yourself?  The result of the ratio of the OSC freq and AGC BW determines the THD of the sine wave which in my case is very low THD.

Comment: The Vref = 0.75 in my design makes this Osc start up instantly with a perfect sine.

Comment: Sunnyskyguy_ perhaps a matter of terminology only? Just one simple question: Do you agree that the mean value of the capacitor voltage (identical to the gate voltage driving the FET) is lower than the peak output voltage of the opamp? And the factor is app. R5/(R5+R7). Yes or no?

Comment: Given his  single supply with  Vcc/2 ref. and the load impedance being so high it is a  negative signal rectifier and the peak would be about 0.3V above the actual negative peak.  However the cap is too small and result is horribly distorted. In my bipolar design the actual diode current is lower and thus closer to a true peak detector. but with a much lower quasi-peak BW than 1/2pi*10k 300pf.  We call this a quasi peak detector , but his cap is far too small. There is a std for audio quasi peak used in all RFI tests soince WWII whenthey discovered audio radio interference

Comment: His Tau= 3us when it should be  10~100us  and the range is far too high for gain control and many other parameters optimized in my design. Capiche?  I think you will agree it is called a "quasi-peak detector" due to rise/fall time BW shaping for audio band or in this case, Fosc

Comment: I did not comment the design (good or bad) or the quality of the produced signal - I rather recommend to concentrate on the core of my concern: Is the shown rectifier a "peak detecor" or is it not? I repeat: It is not because it does not "detect" the peak of the opamps output. Of course, I have no problems if you like to call it "quasi-peak detector". But you should not state that my sentence "This is not a peak detector" would be "incorrect" (as you did in your detailed answer). Agreed?

Comment: your comment can be corrected by adding the words not **performing well with component values shown  as** a peak ( & hold) detector.  But my broader view of the true definition as used by HP since the early days of Spectrum Analyzer design. is that it is a negative peak detector

Comment: Well the design in question certainly does not behave like what most people think of as a peak detector.  Yet the configuration certain is, just the component values are wrong.  So it simply rectifies negative signals insufficient  hold capacitance for for the impedance and frequency involved. THat's the problem. The RC decay time relative to the carrier cycle time may be defined  by the diode load BW ratio or k=RC*f product which needs to be >>20 for < 5% storage error of peak. However QPD's are all defined by rise time with series R & %decay to store peak with the shunt R value. understand ?

Comment: I do not blindly follow wikipedia - neverthelss: "What is a peak detector circuit?
A peak detector is a series connection of a diode and a capacitor outputting a DC voltage equal to the peak value of the applied AC signal." However, in the case under discussion, we have a rectifier which provides a (slightly varying) voltage well below the AC peak (if designed properly). More than that, for the intended purpose of amplitude regulation the mentioned ability to vary the gate control voltage in BOTH directions (and NOT to hold the peak value) is an important requirement.

Comment: Peak detector aka envelope follower aka AGC control circuit aka half wave rectifier.   I'm not sure how many Spectrum Analyzer detectors, AGC detectors or RSSI detectors you have designed in your career, but they all use at least a diode, resistor and a capacitor to follow the signal by some tR,tF and gain or loss requirement i.e. defined by some AC + DC parameters, ie. amplitude demodulator.  FWIW @LvW  back to you...  WHich in this case you suggested improvements but not enough for a rookie to make it work.  So did you test my simulated design for flaws yet?  if any.

Comment: BTW, the WIki definition is the classic simple design of what those only think of.  Peak follower, Track and hold, Peak hold and resample.  I liked Sony's professional compressor audio mixer that sampled peak and adjusted gain by 1dB according to a digital attack decay algorithm .  THere are many and the definition in Wiki doesn't come close to covering a broad range of peak detectors.  ( limited scope)  I don't know any other design such as my simulation that can start a sine oscillator with a Q >1,000 in the 1st cycle. Do you?

Comment: SunnyskyGuy_most probably, the whole discussion is not too important - however, I think you missed the point. My only concern is the DEFINITION - I gave you one. Do you have ANOTHER ONE ?? I do not speak about my carreer, Analyzers, audio mixers or any other stuff. And I do not speak about your design and the simulated start-up time. My only point is (I repeat): A rectifier, which does not detect and hold the peak of a periodic voltage must not be called "peak detector". That`s all !! I suggest to concentrate on the main question and not to discuss how to safely start your oscillator.

Comment: Again your narrow definition does not describe the peak detector used in many other applications such as spectrum analyzers which can have a 10MHz video BW at 10MHz carrier meaning it follows the carrier signal like a rectifier with weak hold filter BW.  The main solution is  of course a higher BW*f product of the peak detector or RC*f > 10 as you suggested. So peak detect **and slow decay** is what you mean. But the simple definition assumes that's what every does, but it isn't