# How to improve and add frequency adjustment function to my DIY wave generator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, oscillator, waveform, function-generator

## Introduction

I want to build a wave generator. I chose wien bridge oscillator(WBO) as my oscillator and I obtain other waveforms by filtering the sine wave I get from WBO. I managed to get a fairly decent wave forms when the switch is at position 1 but nothing near that other combinations. I am looking for ways to improve my design and make it work since it doesnt work as intended.

## Design Intentions

- Adjustable frequency (15 or MHz to 15 Hz)
- Adjustable output peak voltage
- Can be powered with 220V AC city electricity (by transforming to -15/0/15 or -12/0/12 volt outputs)
- Preferably should use WOS as oscillator

## Design and Circuitry Explanation

[image: Circuit]

**I power all the opAmps with 15/-15 volts**

**I used:**

- TL071 OpAmp
- 2 x 1nF capacitors
- 3 x 100k resistors
- 1 x 210k resistor
- 2 x back to back diodes

To build the oscillator. I get a nice sine wave with this setup, which is actually one of the reasons I chose WOS. Even though the signal was clear, the magnitude of output was pretty low (around 750mV) and I wanted to amplify it.

**I used:**

- UA741 OpAmp
- 1 x 100k resistor
- 1 x 10k resistor

To build an amplifying component with gain 10. Now my sine wave was nice and around acceptable magnitudes. Then I wanted to filter and amplify it again by using an integrator OpAmp to gain a square wave.

**I used:**

- TL071
- 1 x 1k resistor
- 1 x 1nF capacitor

I preffered TL071 here again to get rid of the slope of the square wave. TL071 has a higher slew rate around 10V/us as I remember. As you will see the square wave is pretty neat too.

To acquire the triangle wave I used the same circuitry I used to filter the sine wave. At first I tried to use an UA741 but it just gave me the same square wave, I dont know why. Later I just used a low pass filter

**using**

- 1m resistor
- 1nF capacitor

which gave me a rough triangle wave it had peak voltage near to none. So I used TL071 instead of UA741 to apply the same filter I used on sine wave, to the square wave. This gave me a decent triangle wave with a little plateau.

[image: outputs with oscillator having 1nF capacitors and 100k ohm resistors]

*outputs with oscillator having 1nF capacitors and 100k ohm resistors*

In the end, I had a nice sine wave (around 6.5/-6.5 peak voltage), a nice square wave (around 12.5/-12.5 peak voltage) and an acceptable triangle wave (around 12.5/-12.5 peak voltage). To implement the adjustable output peak voltage I thought about using a potentiometer to change the gain of first OpAmp which amplifies the sine wave. To implement the adjustable frequency I thought about putting some capacitors with trimmers. Since for the sake of oscillation C2 should be equal to C1 and I couldnt find a way to change both capacitance exactly the same (like a ganged up potentiometer) while adjusting the frequency, so I abandoned this idea.

I thought maybe using a rotary switch I can switch between frequency mods, which turned out to be a huge dissapointment. In the schematic above you can see the final implementation. when switch is at first position everything is fine. As I switch problem begins.

[image: after switch graphic]

*You can see the switch time exactly. Plot of before and after the switch*

[image: Close up]

*Close up*

There were even times that I get 0 output from every wave form. I need suggestions to:

- Implement adjustable voltage and frequency
- Fix the plateau at triangle wave
- Any opportunity for improvement you see

Thank you.

Comment: It’s hard to make a good multi-function signal generator with high quality but it’s quite different than this

Comment: If you had quality and performance specs , in question , I might help.

Comment: Im sorry what do you mean by quality and performance specs? How can ı get that data? Im fairly new

Comment: Distortion, linearity, sweep range in frequency, amplitude and frequency stability, etc. & the stuff you might expect to see on a multi-function sig gen.  Look them up.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/426130/why-the-wien-oscillator-output-is-a-sine/426135?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C38.9068#426135  Here’s a previous design answer I gave. note that if you put the input cap to V+ instead of ground, it starts oscillating right away.

Comment: https://www.daqarta.com/dw_gen.htm

Comment: I am using proteus and this is the only digital oscilloscope I can find. I will search for those data but I dont think they are available in my SPICE Im sorry.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 what do you mean by the input cap?

Comment: C2 is the only Cap on an input to gnd

Comment: I tried it and I seem to have a more stable sine wave. I think the virtual oscilloscope has problems tho, it doesnt show the plot right away so I cant really see the start point of oscillation.

Comment: @Tombeki Please ask a specific question, you'll get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your circuit carefully, you aren't switching the RCs correctly.

If you are insisting on using a Wien Bridge Oscillator, you should limit it to audio frequencies. Beyond that will be too difficult.

Use a two pole rotary switch to change the capacitance (C1/C2 in my drawing). CircuitLab doesn't have one, use your imagination. Change the cap by a factor of 10 as you rotate the knob.

Use a ganged log potentiometer in series with a smaller value fixed resistor for the resistor (R1/R2 in my drawing). Shoot for about a 11:1 adjustment with the pot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGXW7A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

.

Comment: I realized that I didnt connect the non inverting output to the other branches but when I do  every signal in every position gets heavily distorted! By 11:1 do you mean gain? I think used a rotary switch in my circuit, am I wrong?

Comment: And what do you mean by cap? by just changing the capacitance I can get this through but that means I need two different rotary switches. I used 4.7 resistances and waves became very distorted.

Comment: You need a two pole rotary switch, also known as a ganged switch.

Comment: with this, in a given time, there are two closed loops attached to the rotary switch am I right? I can pair the feedback and filter branches I think. Thanks.

Comment: @Mattman944 - Hi, Please don't go into more details about what switches are needed *here*. The OP has asked a [new question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/561927/how-to-make-a-switch-close-when-another-switch-close) specifically about the switches. So to reduce duplication between the two questions, please leave the switches to *that* question. Thanks.